# How to find a substring in a string variable using a pattern?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, sh

I've got variable containing such strings:

```
zvq:0.001:0.006 hqp:0.006:0.01 pgvqa:0.1:0.01
```

I'd like to find and echo

```
zvq:0.001:0.006
```

or

```
hqp:0.006:0.01
```

or

```
pgvqa:0.1:0.01
```

by using either `zvq` or `pgvqa` or `hqp` patterns, how should I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *using "zvq"* ?

Comment: Given `s="zvq:0.001:0.006 hqp:0.006:0.01 pgvqa:0.1:0.01"`, `echo "${s%% *}"` will give you `zvq:0.001:0.006`. But it's hard to tell what you're really asking. (And what effort you've done to get it.)

Comment: Ah sorry, "zvq" is word I need to find.
So I've got to search for "zvq" and get whole sub-string as result.

Comment: Is `egrep -o 'zvq:[^ ]+'` what you're after?

Comment: Is all about this in my response ;)

Comment: Indeed. Darn unreliable websockets, I left this question open for 20 minutes and didn't see the update. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var='zvq:0.001:0.006 hqp:0.006:0.01 pgvqa:0.1:0.01'
```

then

```
$ grep -Eo 'zvq[^ ]+' <<< "$var"
zvq:0.001:0.006
```

and

```
$ grep -Eo 'pgvqa[^ ]+' <<< "$var"
pgvqa:0.1:0.01
```

and

```
$ grep -Eo 'hqp[^ ]+' <<< "$var"
hqp:0.006:0.01
```

---

If you just want to cut the string based on space, like @janos said in the comments :

```
echo "${var%% *}"
```

using [*bash parameter expansion*](https://wiki.sputnick.fr/index.php/Parameter_expansion)

Comment: `grep -Eo '^zvq[^ ]+'` seems to do job but when I'm trying to use `pgvqa` instead it doesn't find substring. In general I need to look for first word of substring before colon.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo $variable | tr ' ' '\n' | grep $pattern
```

or

```
echo $variable | tr ' ' '\n' | grep "^${pattern}:"
```

example :

```
 variable="zvq:0.001:0.006 hqp:0.006:0.01 pgvqa:0.1:0.01"
 pattern="zvq"

 echo $variable | tr ' ' '\n' | grep $pattern
 zvq:0.001:0.006
```